# Does Service Fabric provide an api to move actors between partitions at runtime

Tags: load-balancing, actor, partitioning, azure-service-fabric, orleans

I stumbled upon a very interesting [paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/optimizing-distributed-actor-systems-for-dynamic-interactive-services/) from Microsoft Research, where they discuss an algorithm to re-distribute actors between servers / partitions based on their "proximity" (defined as number of remote calls to one another) to reduce remote calls across server boundaries.
They applied their prototype to the [Orleans](http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/) framework.
Now I'm wondering if the Service Fabric Actors framework also provides an interface to re-distribute / balance actors at runtime.
The only remotely related information I found in the online documentation [mentions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-concepts-partitioning/) that Service Fabric redistributes partitions based on reported load.

Any insight would be very interesting.

Kind regards,
Pascal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Service Fabric, an Actor's ID determines the partition it lives in. More info [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-platform/). So an Actor can't move from partition to partition. Like you said, the Actor Service replica that owns the partition (with many Actors) be can moved from node to node. (for balancing) By using [placement constraints](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description/) you can influence movements.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the placement constraints, I didn't know about those. I hoped someone from the actual Service Fabric team would give an input if such a feature is planned or not, at least for me it seems crucial for (very) large systems. Nevertheless, thank you for your input.

Comment: You might also be interested in 'affinity': https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-advanced-placement-rules-affinity/. You can put chatty services close together. (while you fix the chattyness problem)